# Choosing particular Fragment to display in Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to modify this app's code: https://github.com/udacity/ud839_ViewPager_Example/tree/quiz
to make MainActivity display TuesdayFragment at start instead of MondayFragment.

I want to learn how to choose the particular fragment.java file that Activity displays when starts.

Some of you may not have time to check code on github, so here it is:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.viewpager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

/**
 * Displays a {@link ViewPager} where each page shows a different day of the week.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find the view pager that will allow the user to swipe between fragments
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        // Create an adapter that knows which fragment should be shown on each page
        SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set the adapter onto the view pager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

and it's layout **activity_main.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Layout for the main screen -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.viewpager.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

TuesdayFragment.java, WednesdayFragment.java and **MondayFragment.java** are very similar, just use different layouts.xml, that display different day of the week text:

```
package com.example.android.viewpager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Fragment that displays "Monday".
 */
public class MondayFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monday, container, false);
    }
}
```

and there is a **SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter.java:**

```
package com.example.android.viewpager;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

/**
 * Provides the appropriate {@link Fragment} for a view pager.
 */
public class SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return new MondayFragment();
        } else if (position == 1){
            return new TuesdayFragment();
        } else {
            return new WednesdayFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

I was reading about fragments and transactions and playing with transaction and replace, trying to force TuesdayFragment to be displayed at start of the MainActivity with ideas like:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewpager, TuesdayFragment).commit();
```

but nothing worked.

**Question:** Can someone be so kind and show me what code needs to be modified/added, for MainActivity to be able to start with whatever Fragment I want? Right now it always starts with MondayFragment.

I'm stuck, so even pushing me in the right direction will be much appreciated at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you set the adapter, you can call this method in your onCreate method:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(indexOfItemYouWantToDisplay)
```

As default is 0, MondayFragment is displayed. Set it to 1, and TuesdayFragment will be displayed.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you KMP!